# OSGI component not being picked up by SCR (ServiceMix)?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am trying to create an OPS4J PAX config DataSource pre-hook to automate database structure integrity checking and updates via Liquibase. According to [this tutorial](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/liquibase/tutorial.md), all I have to do is mark a `PreHook` implementation with a `@Component` annotation giving it a name property and reference that property in the DataSource config, which I have done.

The problem seems to be that the component is never picked by the SCR.

```java
@Component(property = "name=coredbmigrate")
public class LiquibaseMigrator implements PreHook {
    public LiquibaseMigrator() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("PREHOOK INITIALIZED");
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("PREHOOK CALLED");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have added basic outputs to indicate when the component is intatiated and called, and neither of those ever happen.

The generated `OSGI-INF/lv.cps.is.ledger.accounts.db.LiquibaseMigrator.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component name="lv.cps.is.ledger.accounts.db.LiquibaseMigrator">
    <implementation class="lv.cps.is.ledger.accounts.db.LiquibaseMigrator"/>
    <service>
        <provide interface="org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.hook.PreHook"/>
    </service>
    <property name="name" type="String" value="coredbmigrate"/>
</component>
```

`Service-Component` header in `MANIFEST.MF` is also set correctly.

What could be the reason that the component is never instantiated? Or maybe it is but I'm not seeing it?

Comment: How do you see it is not picked up by scr?

Comment: There is no output from the constructor. Is there a better way to check if it's loaded or not?

Comment: What does the `scr:list` command say? This is always the first thing to check with SCR... looking for output from the constructor is unreliable because your component might be working perfectly and still not output anything because it is lazily loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the scr feature installed? By default it is not installed and in this case DS components are silently ignored.

When it is installed you can use the scr:* commands to check the status of your components.

Comment: That was it. I had assumed that SCR was installed by default. A simple `feature:install scr` fixed the problem. Thank you.